# Awaiting a promise across a websocket

Tags: angular, websocket

I need to be able to send requests across a websocket and await them link typical queries.

Because websockets don't send responses instantaneously, I'm using the `onmessage` attribute on the websocket to listen for responses. Each request is sent out with a unique ID so that when receiving the response it can be mapped back to request that sent it.

So right now, the code looks more-or-less like this

```
_requests = new Map();
 
public exec(req) {
  req = {
    payload: {/* stuff */}
    request_id: /* unique ID */
  };
  _requests.set(req.request_id, /*some_callback like () => {} */)
  ws.send(req)
}

// receive
public receive() {
  ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    response = e.data
    requestId = response.request_id
  
    callback = this._requests(requestId)
    callback(response) 

    this._requests.delete(requestId)
}
```

Which is incomplete... Because I want `exec` to return a promise that I can `await` when called from the component that is requesting data.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it similar to this:

```
// send
public exec(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this._requests.set(req.request_id,
        (resp) => {
           if (resp.error) {
             reject(resp)
           } else {
             resolve(resp)
           }
        }
  }
}
// listener
public onReceive() {
  ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    var callback = this._requests.get(response.request_id)
    callback(e.data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you looking for promised based asynchronous communication.

Solution: To achieve this we have to implement a request-response mechanism. Each request has a unique id and waits for a response from a WebSocket server with the same id.

I have written a small javascript module to achieve this in a very clean & easy manner.

I call it "linka", https://github.com/pathikdevani/linka